# How to create object files in a subdir with makefile - C lenguage

Tags: makefile

I'd like to create all my .o files in a subdirectory such as /objects in order to keep my /src organized.

### I already have this:

```c
progr : main.o manipulate_strings.o environment_set.o variables.o segment_private.o rectangle_private.o circle_private.o tree.o dynamic_list.o visibility.o query.o
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -g main.o manipulate_strings.o environment_set.o variables.o segments_private.o rectangle_private.o tree.o dynamic_list.o circle_private.o visibility.o query.o -o progr -lm
    rm *.o

main.o : main.c manipulate_strings.o
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g main.c

manipulate_strings.o : manipulate_strings.c manipulate_strings.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g manipulate_strings.c

environment_set.o : environment_set.c environment_set.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g environment_set.c

variables.o : private/variables.c private/variables.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g private/variables.c -lm

segment_private.o : private/segments_private.c private/segments_private.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g private/segments_private.c -lm

rectangle_private.o : private/rectangle_private.c private/rectangle_private.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g private/rectangle_private.c

circle_private.o : private/circle_private.c private/circle_private.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g private/circle_private.c

tree.o : data_struct/tree.c data_struct/tree.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g data_struct/tree.c

dynamic_list.o : data_struct/dynamic_list.c data_struct/dynamic_list.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g data_struct/dynamic_list.c

visibility.o : visibility.c visibility.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g visibility.c

query.o : query.c query.h
    gcc -fstack-protector-all -std=c99 -c -g query.c -lm
```

---

It works just fine although it fills my src directory with .o files. Any idea how?

Comment: Please edit your question to have proper formatting.  You need to use the compiler's `-o` option to tell it where to put the object files.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.
I was trying a lot more complicated things.

Comment: Note that you'll have to change the target names to be `dir/foo.o` as well: it's critical that your recipe builds the target that you told make it will build, not some other target.